# OpenUI5 - partially rerender control

Tags: sapui5

I am using sap.ui.ux3.DataSet to render hundreds of simple custom controls.

At startup time I would like to only render a few of the items however, and then render the additional items as the user scrolls.

I can add items to the DataSet's underlying model after it's been originally rendered, but because it has to completely re-render there is a poor user experience.

Is there a general pattern for re-rendering part of a control? I'm having a hard time appending items because the render manager is no longer available.

---

Edit: 
I think I can generalize my question after some more reflection:

**When the model of a control is updated, are there ways to partially re-render the control to reflect the change?**

The use-case above is for rendering additional items in the DataSet control after it's initial rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a use case in UI5 tables yet so you may adapt to your needs, but the "plain" HTML 'load-more-as-you-scroll-down' pattern would be

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > ($(document).height() - $(window).height()) * 0.8) { //at 80% scroll-down
       //do your AJAX call for more data
       //also implement check for multiple simultaneous requests
    }
}
```

Not sure how to implement partial rendering of a control though...

Comment: Ok, that's a good start...but the root of this question isn't how to capture the event when it's time to load more items via ajax and do some dom manipulation.
I need to be able to invoke the RenderManager after the initial rendering so I can render more items.